# npm cannot install phantomJS on window

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

[image: screenshot1]
[image]

I use npm to install phantomjs locally,but I got errors.I can use npm install jquery and so on successfully.So I  don`t know what is wrong and how can I install phantomjs ?Was it blocked in China?

Comment: Do you have *PhantomJS.exe* in your `PATH`?

Comment: @MartinZhai,hi,I don`t kown if or not I have PhantomJs.exe in path.How can I make sure?

Comment: I will assume you don't have it. You can download *PhantomJS* at official site, and add the directory where you put *PhantomJS.exe* into system environment variable `PATH`. Then try `npm install phantomjs` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK，I am sure I was blocked.I used `cnpm install phantomjs -g` to install and successed.If you live in China you can use `cnpm` when you can not use `npm` well.
[The link to cnpm](http://npm.taobao.org/)